# Stiff Gas Pedal 03 Corolla

Tags: toyota, corolla, throttle

I have an '03 Corolla with about 87k miles on it. I just bought it a while ago and everything on it seems to run perfect. Recently I've been a bit conscious of how I drive and accelerate and noticed that the gas pedal is a bit stiff (slightly). I decided to see if its just my shoes and took them off while driving. Surprisingly it felt a lot easier to accelerate but still there is a slight pushback. Is it me or do I have to check this and if I do how much would this cost me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much unless it gets worse. Every car's throttle response is different, I've had some that have been really light and others not (clutches are often worse...). I don't know if the corolla uses a cable or an electronic throttle, but if it's the former you could try disconnecting the engine end of the cable and making sure it slides freely - If it doesn't, you can lubricate the cable to free it off (drip a light machine oil onto the inner cable and slide the cable up and down its full range of motion a few times to work the oil down it.)

Driving without shoes can be easier, you have a lot more feeling through the sole of your foot than through a shoe, particularly if you have stiff shoes...

Comment: FYI: 2003 Corolla has a cable-driven throttle

Comment: Definitely check the throttle cable then. There should be an adjuster on it near the throttle body.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rawvJop772E